# app works on the tablet and falls on a smartphone

Tags: java, android

### Logs with my application

[image]
[image]

**What went wrong?**

Comment: You ran out of memory (`OutOfMemoryError`) when loading the background of an `ImageButton`.

Comment: Which version of android do you have on your tablet?

Answer (score 0):

Found this in Google groups:

```
"Usually this happens when you're using Eclipse and it hasn't told ADT to update. Did you try Project > Clean?"
```

Comment: Of course I tried to clean, I think the problem in the picture. oversized image for buttons.